# Am getting ArrayOutOfBounds exception and am not sure why

Tags: java

I am trying to create a dowhile loop to check my array created by user input, and I am getting ArrayOutOfBounds exception. I am unsure as to why, and I am not certain on how to fix it. I am new to coding, so any assistance is appreciated.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        boolean found;
        
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dogs;
    
         System.out.println("How many dogs?");
         dogs = input.nextInt();
         int index;
        
        String[] dognames = new String [dogs];
        Double [] dogweights = new Double [dogs];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < dogs; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter dog name and weight: ");
            dognames[i]= input.next();
            dogweights[i]=input.nextDouble();}
        
        while((!"quit".equals(dognames[dogs])));{
        found = false;
        index = 0;
        while(!found && index < dognames.length)
        {
        if(dognames[index].equals(dognames))
            found = true;
        else
            index++;
        }
        
        if(!found)
            index = -1;
        
        if (index == -1)
            System.out.println("Error");
        
        else
            System.out.println(dognames);
        }
        
        double length = dogweights.length;
 
       
        double sum = 0;
 
       
        for (int i = 0; i < dogweights.length; i++) {
            sum += dogweights[i];
        }
 
        double dogweightsaverage = sum / length;
        
        System.out.print("AHHHHH");
    

    
    
    }
    }
```

I've tried changing the while condition, but that just creates more problems.

Comment: `dognames[dogs]` is *never* going to be valid, when the length of `dognames` is `dogs`. For example, if you've got an array of 2 elements, the indexes will be 0 and 1 - so `array[2]` will always be invalid.

Comment: (As an aside, I'd very strongly encourage you to format your code in a more conventional way. And I doubt that you want the `;` after `while((!"quit".equals(dognames[dogs])))` either - you've got an empty loop body.

Comment: What is happening in this line? `if(dognames[index].equals(dognames))` This is asking if a specific name in the array is equal to the entire array? How is that going to work?...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error **ArrayOutOfBounds** beacuse the **index** different from **dimenssion** so you must so you have to do -1. You should remove **;** after while to go into the while, like that:

```
    while ((!"quit".equals(dognames[dogs -1]))) // i add -1
        { .....}
```